# How to pre-populate for data in Angular 2? Using FormGroup?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am building a form in Angular 2. The process of building the form for submission is straight forward but I also need an edit feature. My problem is that I dont understand how to pre-populate the data in the form from the Backend. I do have a backend service and I am getting data from it. But I have no clue how this data will bind to the existing form.

The code for the form is as follows:-

**Component code**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { DialogRef, ModalComponent, CloseGuard } from 'angular2-modal';
import { BSModalContext } from 'angular2-modal/plugins/bootstrap';
import { ValidationService } from '../../../shared/core/error-messages/validation-service';

import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, FormBuilder, FormArray }
  from '@angular/forms';

export class CustomModalContext extends BSModalContext {
  public num1: number;
  public num2: number;
}

/**
 * A Sample of how simple it is to create a new window, with its own injects.
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'modal-content',
  templateUrl: './custom-modal.component.html'
})
export class CustomModal implements OnInit, CloseGuard, ModalComponent<CustomModalContext> {
  context: CustomModalContext;
  form: FormGroup;

  public wrongAnswer: boolean;

  constructor(public dialog: DialogRef<CustomModalContext>, private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.context = dialog.context;
    this.wrongAnswer = true;
    dialog.setCloseGuard(this);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      'clientName': ['', [Validators.required, ValidationService.isAlphabetNSpace]],
      'hospitalGroup': ['', [Validators.required, ValidationService.isAlphabetNSpace]],
      'addressLineOne': ['', Validators.required],
      'addressLineTwo': ['', Validators.required],
      'city': ['', Validators.required],
      'state': ['', Validators.required],
      'postalCode': ['', Validators.required],
      'deployment': ['', Validators.required],
      'details':this.fb.array([
        this.initDetails()
      ])
    });
  }

  initDetails(){
    return this.fb.group({
          'name':[''],
          'jobTitle':[''],
          'email':[''],
          'systemRole':[''],
          'phoneNumber':['']
        });
  }
  addDetail(){
    const control = <FormArray>this.form.controls['details'];
    control.push(this.initDetails());
  }

  removeDetail(i:number){
    const control = <FormArray>this.form.controls['details'];
    control.removeAt(i);
    console.log(this.form.value)
  }

  onKeyUp(value) {
    this.wrongAnswer = value != 5;
    this.dialog.close();
  }


  beforeDismiss(): boolean {
    return true;
  }

  beforeClose(): boolean {
    return this.wrongAnswer;
  }
}
```

**HTML Code**

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
            <wizard-container>
                <wizard-section title="Account Information">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Client Name *</label>
                                <input id="clientname" maxlength="100" formControlName="clientName" type="text" class="form-control required">
                                <control-messages [control]="form.controls.clientName"></control-messages>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Hospital Group *</label>
                                <input id="hospitalgroup" maxlength="100" formControlName="hospitalGroup" type="text" class="form-control required">
                                <control-messages [control]="form.controls.hospitalGroup"></control-messages>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Address</label>
                                <input id="address1" maxlength="60" formControlName="addressLineOne" type="text" class="form-control required">
                                <control-messages [control]="form.controls.addressLineOne"></control-messages>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Address</label>
                                <input id="address2" maxlength="60" formControlName="addressLineTwo" type="text" class="form-control required email">
                                <control-messages [control]="form.controls.addressLineTwo"></control-messages>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>City</label>
                                <input id="city" maxlength="100" formControlName="city" type="text" class="form-control required">
                                <control-messages [control]="form.controls.city"></control-messages>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>State</label>
                                        <input id="state" maxlength="20" formControlName="state" type="text" class="form-control required email">
                                        <control-messages [control]="form.controls.state"></control-messages>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Postal Code</label>
                                        <input id="postalcode" maxlength="5" formControlName="postalCode" type="text" class="form-control required email">
                                        <control-messages [control]="form.controls.postalCode"></control-messages>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Deployment *</label>
                                <input id="deployment" formControlName="deployment" type="text" class="form-control required email">
                                <control-messages [control]="form.controls.deployment"></control-messages>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </wizard-section>
                <wizard-section title="Module Selection">
                    <p>YYPOYOYOYOYYYOYOY</p>
                </wizard-section>
                <wizard-section title="Create Admin">
                    <div formArrayName="details">
                        <div *ngFor="let detail of form.controls.details.controls; let i=index">
                            <div class="panel-body" [formGroupName]="i">
                                <div class="col-lg-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Name *</label>
                                        <input id="name" type="text" formControlName="name" class="form-control" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Job Title *</label>
                                        <input id="name" type="text" formControlName="jobTitle" class="form-control" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Email *</label>
                                        <input id="name" type="text" formControlName="email" class="form-control" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>System Role *</label>
                                        <input id="name" type="text" formControlName="systemRole" class="form-control" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Phone Number *</label>
                                        <input id="name" type="text" formControlName="phoneNumber" class="form-control" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <button (click)="removeDetail(i)" *ngIf="form.controls.details.controls.length>1">Delete</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" (click)="addDetail()">Add Details</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </wizard-section>
            </wizard-container>
        </form>
```

Please help me to understand where and how can I bind the form with the backend data. Consider the data is coming from a service.(I already know how to write a service only data pre-population is a problem)

Answer (score 9):

To pre-populate data there are two methods of FormGroup instance. setValue & patchValue. After you receive the response from server just set/patch the values using one of these methods

```
this.form.patchValue(YOUR_SERVER_RESPONSE);
```

To know the difference between setValue() and patchValue() read here: [FormGroup](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormGroup-class.html#!#setValue-anchor).

Comment: oh ok. Let me check once :)

Comment: Any comments on binding checkboxes? I am a bit confused on having them

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your comment fully. Do you want to bind pre-defined value to checkboxes? If so then you can bind it to the checked attribute of checkbox input. `<input type="checkbox" [checked]="isChecked">`

Comment: Actually there are checkboxes that have labels and the labels are also coming as a backend service. I am not sure how to bind the checkbox value along with the label values?

Comment: It will be helpful if you ask another question with the server response and detail about what you want to do with the labels and checkboxes in your template.

Answer (score 1):

You are currently building the "form" with empty quotes. To pre-populate the form, replace those with the data you want to use instead. Like so:

```
export class CustomModal implements OnInit, CloseGuard, ModalComponent<CustomModalContext> {
  context: CustomModalContext;
  form: FormGroup;

  public wrongAnswer: boolean;

  constructor(public dialog: DialogRef<CustomModalContext>, private fb: FormBuilder, private clientService: ClientService) {
    this.context = dialog.context;
    this.wrongAnswer = true;
    dialog.setCloseGuard(this);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    let client = this.clientService.getClient();
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      'clientName': [client.clientName, [Validators.required, ValidationService.isAlphabetNSpace]],
      'hospitalGroup': [client.hospitalGroup, [Validators.required, ValidationService.isAlphabetNSpace]],
      'addressLineOne': [client.addressLineOne, Validators.required],
      'addressLineTwo': [client.addressLineTwo, Validators.required],
      'city': [client.city, Validators.required],
      'state': [client.state, Validators.required],
      'postalCode': [client.postalCode, Validators.required],
      'deployment': [client.deployment, Validators.required],
      'details':this.fb.array([
        this.initDetails(client.details)
      ])
    });
  }

  initDetails(clientDetails: ClientDetails){
    return this.fb.group({
          'name':[clientDetails.name],
          'jobTitle':[clientDetails.jobTitle],
          'email':[clientDetails.email],
          'systemRole':[clientDetails.systemRole],
          'phoneNumber':[clientDetails.phoneNumber]
        });
  }
  addDetail(){
    const control = <FormArray>this.form.controls['details'];
    control.push(this.initDetails(new ClientDetails()));
  }

  removeDetail(i:number){
    const control = <FormArray>this.form.controls['details'];
    control.removeAt(i);
    console.log(this.form.value)
  }

  onKeyUp(value) {
    this.wrongAnswer = value != 5;
    this.dialog.close();
  }


  beforeDismiss(): boolean {
    return true;
  }

  beforeClose(): boolean {
    return this.wrongAnswer;
  }
}
```

Comment: This might not work because the formGroup has to exist when the View is created, and thus must be initialized as part of the constructor. In the ngOnInit, use setValue to update the values of the formGroup.

Comment: If you use `*ngIf="form"` in the `<form>` tag, then formGroup does not have to exist when the view is created.

Comment: Ah, good to know, Thanks! I'm new to Angular 2, TypeSCript, etc., and there are some (many) frustrating pieces...

Comment: I have the same issue, I have a createForm() method in ngOnInit for a user profile reactive form that needs to populate from firebase but the form is empty when the page reloads. I know I'll get there just painful.